# Make second pipe not wait for the first one to finish

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I have a long-running program called `my-program`, and I want to see the logs in stdout, but also save them to a file. I also want to prepend datetime to each line.

This is how I am trying to do it:

```
my-program | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 }' | tee out.log
```

The problem is that the second pipe waits for the output from the first one to finish.

Why does it wait? How can I make it so that it processes the output from the first pipe line by line?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presence of the pipe allows applications to buffer their output more efficiently. The second (and third) process do run in parallel with the first, but it may be that the first isn't producing enough output to fill the buffer.

You can get around the problem by using `stdbuf`, but I wouldn't recommend this as a general panacea for every pipeline as it forces output to be line buffered rather than fully buffered:

```
stdbuf -oL my-program | awk '{ print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 }' | tee out.log
```

You might need an additional `stdbuf -oL` in front of the `awk` too. First try it without, and if necessary add it in there too.

Comment: Thanks. Adding `stdbuf -oL` before `awk` fixed my problem, and I didn't have to put it in front of `my-program`. I don't understand why there is no buffering issue if I only have 1 pipe, i.e. remove the `tee`

Comment: If there is a second pipe then awk will buffer its output into (typically) 4k blocks of characters.  You could probably change your awk program to { print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), $0 ; fflush()} as an alternative approach, getting the output flushed after every write.